# InMemory DbContext throws error when integration testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, integration-testing

Error:

> Message: System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity
>   type 'Program' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type
>   with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities,
>   for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no
>   key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for
>   its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities,
>   ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values
>   generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities,
>   ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is
>   attached to the context.

Integration test:

```
public class ProgramControllerIntegrationTests : MappingTestsHelper
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly Repository<ApplicationDbContext> _repository;
        private ProgramService _programService;
        private readonly ProgramController _classUnderTest;
        private readonly ValidatorService _validatorService;
        private readonly FluentValidatorFactory _fluentValidatorFactory;
        private readonly ClaimsService _claimsService;

        public ProgramControllerIntegrationTests()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Configure(c => {
                c.AddRegistry<DependencyInjectionRegistry>();
                c.For<AbstractValidator<CreateViewModel>>().Use<CreateViewModelValidator>();
            });

            _mapper = Mapper.Instance;
            _repository = new Repository<ApplicationDbContext>(GetContextWithData());
            _programService = new ProgramService(_repository, _mapper);
            _fluentValidatorFactory = new FluentValidatorFactory(container);
            _validatorService = new ValidatorService(_fluentValidatorFactory);
            _claimsService = new ClaimsService();
            _classUnderTest = new ProgramController(_programService, _claimsService, _mapper, _validatorService);
        }

        public class GetAll : ProgramControllerIntegrationTests
        {
            [Fact]
            public async void DoRequestForAllPrograms_ReturnSuccessHttpStatusAndListViewModelList()
            {
                var result = await _classUnderTest.GetAll() as ObjectResult; ;

                result.ShouldBeOfType<OkObjectResult>();
                result.StatusCode.ShouldBe(200);
                result.Value.ShouldBeOfType<List<ListViewModel>>();
            }
        }

        public class Create : ProgramControllerIntegrationTests
        {
            [Fact]
            public async void DoRequestForCreateWithCorrectData_ReturnCreatedHttpStatus()
            {
                var createviewmodel = new CreateViewModel
                {
                    Name = "Muskel Deutsche Program",
                    Length = 1,
                    TimesPerWeek = 3,
                    Type = (byte)ProgramTypeEnum.MuscleGain
                };

                var result = await _classUnderTest.Create(createviewmodel) as ObjectResult;

                result.ShouldBeOfType<OkObjectResult>();
                result.StatusCode.ShouldBe(201);
            }

            [Fact]
            public async void DoRequestForCreateWithMissingData_ReturnBadRequestHttpStatus()
            {
                var createviewmodel = new CreateViewModel
                {
                    Type = (byte)ProgramTypeEnum.MuscleGain
                };

                var result = await _classUnderTest.Create(createviewmodel) as ObjectResult;

                result.ShouldBeOfType<BadRequestObjectResult>();
                result.StatusCode.ShouldBe(400);
            }
        }

        private ApplicationDbContext GetContextWithData()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .Options;

            var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);

            var programs = new List<Context.Models.Program>
            {
                new Context.Models.Program
                {
                    CreatedBy = "d0806514-cbce-47b7-974f-c50f77d5e89c",
                    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 10),
                    Id = 1,
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    Length = 1,
                    ModifiedBy = "d0806514-cbce-47b7-974f-c50f77d5e89c",
                    ModifiedDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 10),
                    Name = "Big Muscle",
                    TimesPerWeek = 1

                },
                //new Context.Models.Program
                //{
                //    CreatedBy = "d0806514-cbce-47b7-974f-c50f77d5e89c",
                //    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 10),
                //    Id = 1,
                //    IsActive = true,
                //    IsDeleted = false,
                //    Length = 1,
                //    ModifiedBy = "d0806514-cbce-47b7-974f-c50f77d5e89c",
                //    ModifiedDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 10),
                //    Name = "Stay Fit",
                //    TimesPerWeek = 1

                //}
            };

            context.AddRangeAsync(programs);

            context.SaveChanges();

            return context;
        }
    }
```

Problem arises at DoRequestForCreateWithCorrectData_ReturnCreatedHttpStatus method where I use context to add new item into memory DB. Same problem arises when I want to add more items into context at the same time, so I think I am doing to initialisation wrong way.

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but `SaveChanges` after `AddRangeAsync` w/o `await` or `Wait`-ing it to complete doesn't sound good. Why not simply `AddRange`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that Id's from premade data were 1 and 1, so this is first mistake, why both didn't work together. Another problem was when creating new record it created with Id 1, which was already used by premade data, so I just changed IDs in premade to 98 and 99.

```
    private ApplicationDbContext GetContextWithData()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .Options;

        var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);

        var programs = new List<Context.Models.Program>
        {
            new Context.Models.Program
            {
                CreatedBy = "d0806514-cbce-47b7-974f-c50f77d5e89c",
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 10),
                Id = 98,
                IsActive = true,
                IsDeleted = false,
                Length = 1,
                ModifiedBy = "d0806514-cbce-47b7-974f-c50f77d5e89c",
                ModifiedDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 10),
                Name = "Big Muscle",
                TimesPerWeek = 1

            },
            new Context.Models.Program
            {
                CreatedBy = "d0806514-cbce-47b7-974f-c50f77d5e89c",
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 10),
                Id = 99,
                IsActive = true,
                IsDeleted = false,
                Length = 1,
                ModifiedBy = "d0806514-cbce-47b7-974f-c50f77d5e89c",
                ModifiedDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 10),
                Name = "Stay Fit",
                TimesPerWeek = 1

            }
        };

        context.AddRange(programs);

        context.SaveChanges();

        return context;
    }
```